# Eliminate results from a relationship (add an ON condition to JOIN)

Tags: views, 9

I need to add an ON condition to a views JOIN. I cannot use a contextual filter, as it will filter out results altogether, and I need to get a result regardless (there are other joins). So I need to ensure the filter happens on the JOIN, and not as a WHERE condition.

To be more specific, I want to show a value when no relationship exists. The relationship is from one NODE type to another NODE of the same type, and I don't want the current node retrieved. So the ON condition should be `AND join_table.id != original_table.id`.

I'm new to altering views queries. Can anyone provide assistance either on how to add an ON condition to a Views query either through the admin UI (if possible) or through a query alter?

Thank you

Comment: Does this help? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/251700/48114

Comment: Almost, but not. It shows how to add an 'ON' condition, but the condition is for a fixed value, where I the condition to be on another table column.

Comment: Can you use some of the other options listed here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21join%21JoinPluginBase.php/property/JoinPluginBase%3A%3Aextra/8.2.x

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. I played with it for a while, but I don't see any combination that allows me to get the right tables and columns referenced in the query, particularly as `value` is required, but I'm not working with a value, I'm working with a column name.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to help from sonfd above, I was able to come up with a solution of sorts. I was not able to compares the two columns as I was trying to, but I was able to use `$view->args` to come up with the result I wanted.

To answer the question on how to add an additional ON condition to JOIN, you can do the following:

```
function HOOK_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, QueryPluginBase $query) {
  if ($view->id() == VIEW_ID && $view->current_display === DISPLAY_ID) {
    $table = $query->getTableInfo(TABLE_NME);
    $table['join']->extra = empty($table['join']->extra) ? [] : $table['join']->extra;
    $table['join']->extra[] = [
      'field' => FIELD_NAME,
      'operator' => '!=',
      'value' => VALUE, // In my case $view->args[0],
    ];
  }
}
```